# - Exploit aborted due to failure: not-found: Can't find base64 decode on target

Tags: php, apache, metasploit, ubuntu

So. I am having some issues at metasploit.
I am trying to exploit
exploit/multi/http/wp_crop_rce.

I am using Docker, in order to install wordpress version: 4.8.9.

PHP 7.2.12 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2018 22:58:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

wordpress version: 4.8.9
metasploit:latest version

```
    Module options (exploit/multi/http/wp_crop_rce):
    
       Name       Current Setting  Required  Description
       ----       ---------------  --------  -----------
       PASSWORD   password1234     yes       The WordPress password to authenticate with
       Proxies                     no        A proxy chain of format type:host:port[,type:host:port][...]
       RHOSTS     172.17.0.1       yes       The target host(s), range CIDR identifier, or hosts file with syntax 'file:<path>'
       RPORT      8000             yes       The target port (TCP)
       SSL        false            no        Negotiate SSL/TLS for outgoing connections
       TARGETURI  /                yes       The base path to the wordpress application
       USERNAME   admin            yes       The WordPress username to authenticate with
       VHOST                       no        HTTP server virtual host
    
    
    Payload options (php/meterpreter/reverse_tcp):
    
       Name   Current Setting  Required  Description
       ----   ---------------  --------  -----------
       LHOST  192.168.91.130   yes       The listen address (an interface may be specified)
       LPORT  4444             yes       The listen port
    
    
    Exploit target:
    
       Id  Name
       --  ----
   0   WordPress
```

Expected behavior

Should be run without any error and meterpreter session will open.

Current behavior -> Can't find Base64 decode error.

```
[+] Authenticated with WordPress
[*] Preparing payload...
[*] Uploading payload
[+] Image uploaded
[*] Including into theme
[-] **Exploit aborted due to failure: not-found: Can't find base64 decode on target**
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

Ubuntu machine

Comment: Does the target have "base64 decode" ?

Comment: @schroeder, how can I check that? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Paul you should get access into the Docker container and check if the command is there. Probably it wont be there so add it into the Dockerfile or simply do an apt install base64 within the container

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving a full answer to this, I will go through the steps I would take to figure out what might be going wrong here.

To debug the issue, you can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/multi/http/wp_crop_rce.rb) of the exploit.

The main function is `exploit`. It first uses metasploit functions to check if wordpress is running and if you can log in with the provided credentials. Let's assume for now that they work correctly. What we can see is that there is no permission check in the exploit (so it will continue to the next step even if you log in as say subscriber).

Then it performs the actual exploit (sending the request to crop an image in  `crop_image` and `change_path`). It doesn't validate if any of this works or not.

Then it performs the second stage of the exploit (LFI in `include_theme`). Here, it has some checks on whether the user can create posts.

Finally, it checks if if the shell was correctly placed in `check_for_base64` and if successful creates a backdoor.

This is where the exploit fails for you. Specifically, we can see that the `Can't find base64 decode on target` error means that a request to `TARGETURI` returns a 200 (as expected), but that it doesn't contain the result of the injected command.

Taken all of this, we can see that the base64 error basically means "exploit not successful", but that it doesn't necessarily mean it's related to base64.

Possible problems include:

- you are using a user that does not have the required permissions. Eg by default, using a user in the contributor role should result in the error you get (they can create posts, but not upload files).
- you are running wordpress on windows, where the injected `echo #{test_string} | base64 -d` command will fail.
- the used wordpress version is not vulnerable, or some custom configuration prevents exploitation
- there is a (possibly deliberate) error in the exploit code.

You can narrow the problem down by eg:

- testing the issue with a wordpress admin user
- running wordpress on linux or adapting the injected command if running on windows.
- debugging the exploit code & manually exploiting the issue:

  - add logging to the exploit to show you the full HTTP responses (&requests). Are they what you would expect? Or are there any errors that might show a problem?
  - manually create the required requests to exploit the issue (you can start with the requests sent by the exploit). Is this working? If so, how are the requests different from the requests the exploit sends? If not, how can you adapt the requests so that they do work?
  - If none of the above works, add logging to the relevant wordpress functions. Are they doing what they should be doing? Or are there any errors?

Comment: Showing an answer is useful. Providing a methodology like this is a goldmine. Being able to analyze source code is a mandatory task on this field and it helps you out understanding the problem.